# How can I get all capabilities for a particular user?

Tags: multisite, capabilities

I am trying to get an array of all caps for a given user. But the method get_role_caps() only returns the custom capabilities assigned to the user. The array does not contain the caps from the default WP role.

In my case, as super admin of the multisite, I have added a cap called 'custom_cap' to my user, on blog id 2.

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$uid = $user->ID;
echo 'Here are the user caps for user '.$uid.':';
print_r($user->get_role_caps());
```

That code gives me only the custom cap, not a complete list of my user's caps:

```
Here are the user caps for user 1:
Array
(
    [custom_cap] => 1
)
```

How can I get a complete array of a user's caps? Do I have to loop all roles and build an array with `current_user_can()` on each role's caps? That's tedious.

The reason I need to have an array is that I'm enqueuing it for jQuery to pick up off the page. User caps will affect the menus that jQuery builds. Once I know all the caps that my app needs, I could build a custom query for those caps, but it seems like I should be able to gather all user caps with this method of the WP_User class. What am I missing?

[**WP_User::get_role_caps()**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/get_role_caps/)